# how to objective c(gcc command) program from java

Tags: java, objective-c

```
**
```

1. i am trying to run objective c program from java..
   every time geting this error..

Main error is java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\store\1436014813635\panna.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

help me..
thanks in advance..

---

**

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> compileAndExecute(Code code, String folderName) {


    Map<String, Object> finalResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {
        String folderPath = "C:\\store\\" + folderName + "\\";
        String sourceFilePath = "C:\\store\\" + folderName + "\\panna.m";
        String outputFilePath = "C:\\store\\" + folderName + "\\panna.exe";


        File fileSaveDir = new File(folderPath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(sourceFilePath);
        log.info("code :"+code.getCode());
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(code.getCode().getBytes());
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(file, true)
                .getChannel();
        channel.write(buf);
        channel.close();
        String command = "gcc -o " + outputFilePath +" "
                +sourceFilePath+"  -I C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -std=c99 -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString";
        System.out.print("Command  :"+command);
        finalResult = PannaUtils.runProcessObjectiveC(command, folderName);
        log.info("finalResult "+finalResult.get("success")+folderName);


            log.info("class Name:" + outputFilePath);

            finalResult = PannaUtils.runProcessObjectiveC(outputFilePath, folderName);
            log.info("finalResult "+finalResult.get("success")+folderName);


            //PannaUtils.getTestCaseResults(folderName, finalResult, code, outputFilePath);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finalResult;


}



//runProcessObjectiveC from here.
public static Map<String, Object> runProcessObjectiveC(String command,
        String folderName) {

    _log.info(command);

    Map<String, Object> afterExecutionOutput = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try{
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    ProcessTimeoutThread.addProcess(pro);

    long afterExecTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    _log.info(""+afterExecTime);

    String error = printLines(command + " error:", pro.getErrorStream());

    pro.waitFor();
    _log.info("error sop"+error);
    _log.info("got exit vlue :"
            + pro.exitValue() );
    if (pro.exitValue() > 0) {

        afterExecutionOutput.put("success", error);

    } else {

        afterExecutionOutput.put("success", error);
    }



    }
 catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        _log.info("Main error is "+e.toString());

}
    return afterExecutionOutput;
}
```

Comment: Error is obvious. Do you have that file in the location you have specified?

Comment: yes i have file on this location with .m extention

Comment: Then why are you trying to run a file with .exe extension?

Comment: becoz after compilation of program it wil generate .exe file ..

Comment: Then you may need to make sure that compilation is happening correctly.

Comment: at compilation time also giving same error..